# Как переделать 2d array в 3d?

Tags: python, numpy

При таком коде

```
img = (io.imread('file_example_TIFF_1MB.tiff', as_gray=True))[:,:,:3]
```

выдает такую ошибку

```
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 2-dimensional, but 3 were indexed
```

Type изображения

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Вопрос- как сделать так, чтобы изображение стало 3д? Это надо для работы библиотеки, с 2д она не работает.

Comment: а вы точно понимаете разницу что такое 3д-изображение и 3д-массив? :D

Comment: Что, вот прямо так и говорит "НЕ РАБОТАЮ"? Может бы покажете нам (в соответствии с требованиями форума, которые вы почему-то позволяете себе не выполнять) пример своего когда, который "Не работает". Что бы мы хотя-бы поняли, кто это загадочное ваше "оно", которое не работает.